# Cmake error when compiling rabbitmq-c

Tags: cmake, rabbitmq

Folks, Am trying to build the rabbitmq C library. Following the instructions closely from the site (https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c), and am running into the following issue:

```
if [ ! -d "build" ]; then
  mkdir build
fi
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build .
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
cmake --build . --target install
```

rabbitmq-c-0.4.1/build/install" does not exist

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: What is the output of the last command? It should tell you where it installs to.

Comment: http://pastie.org/8301310

Comment: Looks like you need to install two required libraries first (http://cyberelk.net/tim/software/xmlto/ and http://rpm5.org/files/popt/)

Comment: Are you running this on jenkins? If so, could it be that jenkins can not create the output directory `/opt/jenkins/ws/workspace/blah/LogApi/c/rabbitmq-c-0.4.1/build/install`?. Try to add the line `mkdir install` after `cd build`.

Comment: Yep, was Jenkins.  Problem wasnt output directory, but cmake not understanding the --target flag (yet) :).  Running make/make install is the fix.

Answer (score 1):

correct build steps:

```
if [ ! -d "build" ]; then
  mkdir build
fi
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build .
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
make
make install
```